# Node.js app.post does not populate MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm running Node.js, Express, Mongoose and Mongodb locally and have this code in my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());

// Decaler Mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost','tinyreports');

// Require the Report model
var models = require('./models/reports.js');

app.post('/report/add', function(req, res) {
    var title = req.body.title;
    var recipients = req.body.recipients;

    var report = new models.Report({title:title});
    report.save( function(err, report) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        res.json({title:report.title});
    });

});

app.listen(3000);

console.log('server_start');
```

I also have the following model(reports.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var reportsSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String
});

exports.Report = mongoose.model('Report', reportsSchema);
```

When I run a cURL post `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"title":"test"}' http://localhost:3000/report/add` to populate the database nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something wrong with my code or the whole set up?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems. How are you verifying the DB content? Have you tried some `console.log` calls inside `/report/add` to confirm things are working as you expect?

Comment: I just tried, your code works fine, maybe try to upgrade all your libs to latest?

Comment: @PeterLyons I do a res.json with the title and it returns a nice array so it should work. When I do a db.tinyreports.save({title:"test"}) in mongo shell it populates the database nicely. But nothing when I run my code. Strange...

Comment: @sza everything seems up to date. I get a warning though when I open mongo shell: Tue Jul 23 23:58:21.732 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000

Comment: Oh so is there a schema mismatch String vs Array? Is req.body.title an array instead of a string? Are you getting recipients and title criss-crossed somehow?

Comment: req.body.title is a string. I have removed req.body.recipients as it is not used. Still the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out and there was nothing wrong with my code but since I'm new to MongoDB I looked in the wrong place in the database and thus couldn't find any entries...DOH!

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var reportsSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String
});

module.export = mongoose.model('Report', reportsSchema); 


var report = new models({title:title});
    report.save( function(err, report) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        res.json({title:report.title});
    }); 

change exports.report to module.export and var report =new models({})
```